# Why does ingesting through LightIngest.exe add 5 minutes delay in the queue?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am ingesting a local parquet file which is as small as just 183 KB.

```
PS C:\Users\user\Downloads\microsoft.azure.kusto.tools.5.4.2\tools> .\LightIngest.exe `
  "https://ingest-adx.centralus.kusto.windows.net/;Fed=True" `
  -database:"wd" -table:"test" `
  -source:"C:\Users\user\Downloads\exp\test" -pattern:"*.parquet" -format:"parquet"
LightIngest invoked with the following arguments: https://ingest-adx.centralus.kusto.windows.net/;Fed=True -database:wd -table:test -source:C:\Users\user\Downloads\exp\test -pattern:*.parquet -format:parquet

Please review the run parameters:

    Connection string      : https://ingest-adx.centralus.kusto.windows.net/;Fed=True
    -database              : wd
    -table                 : test

    -sourcePath            : C:\Users\user\Downloads\exp\test
    -pattern               : *.parquet
    -creationTimePattern   :
    -format                : parquet
    -ignoreFirstRow        : False

    -compression           : 10
    -ingestTimeout (min)   : 60
    -dontWait              : False


Press [Ctrl+Q] to abort, press any other key or wait for 10 seconds to proceed
==> Starting...
ListAndFilterFiles: enumerating files under 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\exp\test'
==> Items discovered: [      1], filtered: [      1], posted for ingestion: [      1]
    Done. Time elapsed: 00:00:02.1317334
    Items discovered: [      1], filtered: [      1], posted for ingestion: [      1]
==> Waiting for ingestion completion...
==> Waiting for ingest operation(s) completion (will timeout after 60 minutes)...
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:00:00.2823859
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:00:30.4223658
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:01:00.5649914
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:01:30.7049284
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:02:00.8459706
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:02:30.9859844
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:03:01.1265852
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:03:31.2669361
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:04:01.4074579
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:04:31.5469210
==> [      0] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:05:01.6859146
==> [      1] out of [      1] ingest operations completed. Time elapsed: 00:05:31.8246008
    Successfully completed [      1] out of [      1] ingest operations.
==> Done.
```

Note how much time take the ingestion. Querying the destination table in ADX shows that ingestion is indeed delayed. It starts soon after `Time elapsed: 00:05:01...` and thus finishes on the next check.

Exactly the same thing happens if I put my parquet file on a storage account and use syntax like

```
`-source:https://{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net/container?{SAS} -prefix:exp/test`
```

The delay is again 5 minutes.

If I launch ingestion from the storage account as

```
.ingest into table test
(h'https://{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net/container/exp/test/my_file.parquet?{SAS}')
with (format='parquet')
```

it start immediately and takes milliseconds to complete.

Please assist, why does this delay happen and how to fix it? Having this big delay renders `LightIngest.exe` just unusable.

Comment: See answer below, as to running the ".ingest" command against the query endpoint, you are bypassing the ingestion management service and all load management / error handling / batching the ingestion service offers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in batching stage in the ingestion service, that is there to make the ingestion process less resource consuming. It defaults to 5 min or 1GB of data.
This can be controlled and overridden on database or table level.
See [IngestionBatchingPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/batchingpolicy) article for more details.
Keep in mind that when you change this policy, it will take the ingestion service several minutes to pick up the changes.